# Meteor: How to keep showing profile avatar after logged out?

Tags: meteor

After reading Discover Meteor, I'm trying to customize microscope to further practice my meteor skills.

I am using accounts-twitter and hope to display the user's twitter profile pic on each of their post submission. I user the following helper to get the post's author id in post_item.js

```
Template.postItem.helpers({
  username: function () {
    owner = this.userId;
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({
      _id: owner
    });
    return user;
  }
});
```

And then in post_item.html I use the following to display the profile pic:

```
<img class="pull-right" src="{{username.profile.avatar}}">
```

If I've logged in my account, I can see my profile pic next to all of my submitted posts. However, when I log out, all the profile pics will be disappeared.

Sorry for the newbie questions. Any pointers are welcome.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. I forgot that by default, Meteor only publishes the logged in user. Hopefully the following answer will help other meteor newbies.

Server:

```
Meteor.publish("allUsers", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({}, {
    fields: {
      profile: 1
    }
  });
});
```

Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('allUsers');
```

Then you will be able to load all the user's profile pics using the following:

```
<img src="{{username.profile.avatar}}">
```